# Cannot resolve "An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com, publish

I'm trying to publish my C# project to an executable in order to distribute it. However, I've referenced 'Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary' and since including it, my project publishes but then crashes on execution with:

```
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found:
    package: 'Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary', version: '1.0.0.0'
    path: 'Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll'
```

So far I have tried:

- Setting the Copy Local and Embed Interlop Types properties for Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary to every combination of true/false.
- Setting the below tag to true/false in the .csproj file.

```
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
```

- Installing the System.Runtime.InteropServices NuGet package.

My .csproj file currently looks like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Project</RootNamespace>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll">
      <Guid>f935dc20-1cf0-11d0-adb9-00c04fd58a0b</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Other references in the project, like to Newtonsoft work fine. I've consulted every thread I can find across the web pertaining to this. The closest I came to another thread describing my problem was [Could not load file or assembly Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945154/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-interop-iwshruntimelibrary/23519912) but I found no useful info there either.

Ideally, I want to just click publish and publish to a folder on my desktop - preferably as the single .exe but the whole folder is fine if it works. I am unaware if I am perhaps missing a step somewhere as I've never used the publish function before. I'm at a loss for what to try next. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How are you publishing at the moment?

You should be able to run the publish command with a flag to tell it to publish as a single file :

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

More info here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/

But as for your particular issue. When publishing as a single file (Which you may already be doing), there is some level of treeshaking involved to try and limit which dependencies it's publishing. In some cases, if you are referencing a library that is loaded using reflection or similar, then ILLinker doesn't know that it's actually being referenced and used.

To get around this, you can add to your csproj file the following :

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then publish your project like so :

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

More info on how ILLinker works here : https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/27/the-publishtrimmed-flag-with-il-linker/